# How to call list of package methods dynamically in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

I have a scenario that I want to execute dynamically fetched methods from a cursor with different arguments. Those argument values are replaced (using `Get_Parameter_Value___(head_rec_.objkey,parameter_);` ) with values in a loop as you can see in the following example.

```
PROCEDURE Dynamic_exe(
    keyvalue_ IN VARCHAR2)
IS 
param_str_        VARCHAR2(2000);
temp_param_str_   VARCHAR2(2000);
method_stmt_      VARCHAR2(100);

CURSOR get_method IS
  SELECT exe_method
  FROM method_tab

BEGIN

param_str_        := Substr(rec_.exe_method,Instr(rec_.exe_method,'(')+1,(Instr(rec_.exe_method,')')-1)-Instr(rec_.exe_method,'('));
temp_param_str_   := param_str_;
method_stmt_      := rec_.exe_method;

WHILE temp_param_str_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
   IF (Instr(temp_param_str_,',') > 0 )THEN                
       parameter_          := trim(Substr(temp_param_str_,1,Instr(temp_param_str_,',')-1));
       temp_param_str_     := Substr(temp_param_str_,Instr(temp_param_str_,',')+1);
   ELSE
      parameter_          := trim(temp_param_str_);
      temp_param_str_     := NULL;
   END IF;
   parameter_value_  := Get_Parameter_Value___(head_rec_.objkey,parameter_);            
   method_stmt_      := REPLACE(method_stmt_,parameter_,''''||parameter_value_||'''');
END LOOP; 

FOR rec_ IN get_method LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN '||method_stmt_||'; END;';
END LOOP;

END Dynamic_exe;
```

This is not safe, SQL injection can be done for this, I need a solution, associated with bind variables, Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What happened when you ran your code? Did you get any errors? If so, post them. Tell us what exactly do you expect us to correct in your code?

Comment: @KaushikNayak sorry, I had to leave my seat for a while before I completed the question. Now it is properly updated. Please check

Comment: Well, the most appropriate way to do this is to redesign your application.Instead of storing program names in a table and executing them dynamically, you should have a main procedure in which  you should run appropriate  sub-procedures based on the main arguments.

Comment: No, It has to be there. Because it is a user value. User register a method to validate fields in a separate place.

Comment: That was the reason I said saying the design is sub-optimal.  User is only concerned about passing relevant data for processing. A method that is invoked should be independent of user's data. Anything that's part of an application should be able to call the same program and then deviate based on the data.User shouldn't have a control on the invocation of independent and isolated programs.

Comment: PL/SQL has a mechanism for storing code, and it's called a package. Or, if you can store object instances in `method_tab` instead of strings, then you can pass the object as a parameter into a procedure that can invoke its method without dynamic code. If it was clearer what you needed to achieve I could write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can eliminate the possibility of SQL injection by using `DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME` to protect the method name, and use `DBMS_SQL` and bind variables to protect the arguments.

`DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME` throws an error if the value is not the same as an existing object.  (Although for packages it only checks that the package name exists, not the procedure name.  But the procedure name must still be a realistic name.)

For example, if the package name exists, the function will simply return the name:

```
SQL> select dbms_assert.SQL_OBJECT_NAME('test_package.test_procedure') name from dual;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_package.test_procedure
```

But any SQL injection shenanigans will raise an exception (which you can catch and handle if necessary):

```
SQL> select dbms_assert.sql_object_name('; delete from employees;') from dual;
select dbms_assert.sql_object_name('; delete from employees;') from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-44002: invalid object name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 401
```

Instead of building the entire statement as a string, add `:bind_variable_n` and `DBMS_SQL` to run it.

So the final string will look something like this (add the bind variable numbers in the loop):

```
method_stmt_ := 'begin '||method_name||'(:1, :2); end;';
```

Executing a dynamic number of bind variables requires `DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE`.  Switching from native dynamic SQL to `DBMS_SQL` is going to be annoying, but it will let you pass in the bind variables without any injection concerns.